# C++ Poco ODBC issue with setting char type in sql

Tags: c++, odbc, poco

Have encountered an strange behaviour in Poco.

I am connecting to MSSQL and running a simple stored procedure.

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdatePrice]
    @PID INT,
    @Ask float,
    @Bid float,
    @Currency NVARCHAR(50),
    @TradeDate char(12)
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Price WHERE PID = @PID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Price
        SET Ask = @Ask,
            Bid = @Bid,
            Currency = @Currency,
            TradeDate = @TradeDate
        WHERE PID = @PID;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Price (PID, Ask, Bid, Currency, TradeDate)
        VALUES (@PID, @Ask, @Bid, @Currency, @TradeDate);
    END
END
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[sp_UpdatePrice] TO [public] AS [dbo]
GO
```

But I am receiving the following error

```
SQLSTATE = 42000
Native Error Code = 2628
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated in table 'msdb.dbo.Price', column 'TradeDate'. Truncated value: '2'.
```

Code:

```
struct price
{
    std::string id;
    std::string currency;
    float ask
    float bid;
    std::string trade_date;
};
ODBC::Connector::registerConnector();
Session session("ODBC", "...");
Statement statement(session);

// create dummy price
price price{...};
// Bind parameters to the statement
statement << "{call sp_UpdatePrice(?,?,?,?,?) }",
    use(price.trade_date()), ...;  // Other parameters

// Execute the stored procedure
statement.execute();

// Unregister the ODBC connector
ODBC::Connector::unregisterConnector();
```

I have a simple price struct, the data comes from the wire. The date is a string in this format "21 MAR 2024".

As a note, this is legacy application being migrated. Unless I really have to update stored procedures, I would prefer not to. Or perhaps not use Poco if its not the best tool for the job.

At this point I want to re-use what is, and be able to add Poco to improve on the code base.

Comment: Can you show us the DDL of `[dbo].[Price]`?